# mutable globals cannot be imported: globalImport.type.isMutable

Tags: smart-contract

I compile hello.cpp in the examples folder in eosio.cdt version1.3.1, which has a lot of updates compares to version 1.2.X. then completely follow the smart contracts tutorials in https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract. Compile succeeds without error, but when I upload the contract to nodeos(version 1.3.2-dirty),

compile cpp:  `eosio-cpp -abigen hello.cpp -o hello.wasm`

set contract: `cleos set contract hello ./hello -p hello@active`

I get : `Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM`

Nodeos raise error:

```
2018-10-17T05:55:10.012 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:580           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
2018-10-17T05:55:10.013 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:581           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3070003 wasm_serialization_error: Serialization Error Processing WASM
mutable globals cannot be imported: globalImport.type.isMutable{}
thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:42 validate pending console output:{"console":""}
thread-0  apply_context.cpp:61 exec_one
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.
I can upload and run the hello demo on nodeos and eosio-cpp version 1.3.1, but something goes wrong after updating.

Answer (score 1):

answer myslef. it seems that wasm&abi files compiled by eosio-cpp is not acceptable by current nodeos version. use eosiocpp instead and the issue is solved. I don't known why this happend cause the eosio-cpp is recommended officially